# How can you only an ADF execute task based on a variable value

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have only been able to find answers to this based on SSIS.
I have a chain of tasks within ADF that I'd only like to execute based on the evaluated value of a parameter within the container.

I've explored the if condition task but it seems to require an activity assigned per condition (e.g. true or false). I am thinking there has to be a way to simply evaluate a parameter value and then based on the value of the parameter determine whether to abort or execute the subsequent chain of tasks.

I am very familiar with SSIS but ADF seems to lack some of the simplicity especially for this particular task.

So what is the simplest way to proceed to another ADF execute task based on a variable value?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but can you explain how this is different than an IF condition?

Comment: Perhaps the IF condition may be viable but the IF task seems to require an activity assignment within its true and false containers. In my case, I already have an "Script" activity that executes and simply requires evaluation of the result to branch execution of the next tasks. So maybe I may be the dense one b/c of my lack of understanding of the IF container. I'll explore some more to see if I can make any sense of it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF supports only if activity for the above kind of True or false condition checking.

```
if(True)
{
    True activities
}
else
{
    False activities
}
```

In ADF also if activity works like above.

[image]

If you don't want to use if activity, you can use a **set variable for condition checking like below**.

Use **success of set variable for True activities and failure for False activities**. Here I have used two set variables for True and False activities.

[image]

You can see for T**rue of dynamic content if**, I have given a string value to string variable by **which activity will succeed(True activities)**. For **false of dynamic content if**, I am assigning **integer value to string variable which will generate error(False activities).**

**Boolean variable var is `True`:**

[image]

**Boolean variable var is `False`:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was using the IF Container incorrectly. I thought I could use the container in much the same way as you've described using the if checking in the set variable example. I didn't know activities were required inside of the container. Your answer provided the clarity I required. Thank you